# Random can't load type Startup error in unit test project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, vstest

I am consistently getting a `Can't load type Services.Tests.Startup in 'Services.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'` error when executing my tests. This error is occurring only for one project but I am unable to pinpoint what the problem could be. Would the community have an input on what could be wrong?

```
========== Starting test run ==========
[xUnit.net 00:00:00.03] xUnit.net VSTest Adapter v2.4.3+1b45f5407b (64-bit .NET 6.0.0-rc.2.21480.5)
[xUnit.net 00:00:11.90]   Starting:    Services.Tests
[xUnit.net 00:00:12.05]     Services.Tests.SendGridEmailSenderTest.SendEmailAsync [FAIL]
[xUnit.net 00:00:12.05]       System.InvalidOperationException : Can't load type Services.Tests.Startup in 'Services.Tests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
[xUnit.net 00:00:12.08]   Finished:    Services.Tests
========== Test run finished: 1 Tests (0 Passed, 1 Failed, 0 Skipped) run in 13.7 sec ==========
```

**Failing source code:**

```
public class Program
    {
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddRecognitionServices(hostContext.Configuration);
                });
        }
    }

public class SendGridEmailSenderTest
    {
        readonly IServiceProvider _services =
            Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[] { }).Build().Services;
        private IOptions<DataAccess.Models.Config.Constants> constants;
        private IOptions<SendGridEmailSettings> sendGridEmailSettings;
        public SendGridEmailSenderTest()
        {
            constants = _services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DataAccess.Models.Config.Constants>>();
            sendGridEmailSettings = _services.GetRequiredService<IOptions<SendGridEmailSettings>>();
        }
        [Fact]
        public async Task SendEmailAsync()
        {
            var iLoggerSendGridEmailSender= new Mock<ILogger<SendGridEmailSender>>();
            var sendGridEmailSender=new SendGridEmailSender(
                sendGridEmailSettings,constants, iLoggerSendGridEmailSender.Object);
            await sendGridEmailSender.SendEmailAsync("ajitgoel@gmail.com", "Subject Text", 
                "Email message");
        }
}
```

Comment: Are the csproj dependencies of all your projects consistent? Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Thank you @Chaodeng, I was able to workaround the issue by creating a new project and adding the project references (and code) manually.

Comment: I've found I've just ran into the same issue. It was as simple as having the Startup.cs in a namespace who's name was different from the project's name.
E.g. Startup.cs was located in Tests.e2e.integration, whilst the project was called e2e.integration.